How to fix the uri-mismatch error in using Google cloud Oauth credentials
I'm trying to use Google Cloud Oauth provider in my Next JS application's production. I have configured my production server using Nginx. The domains and callback url's I have added in the concent screen is working fine in localhost as well as in vercel deployment. But in production environment. I have configured like this, 
But when I try to access the google provider in my application it's throwing me the error as uri-mismatch. If I see the error details, it's showing me the localhost:3000's callback url, which I haven't configured in the console.
What's happening here ? I can't able to understand. Any help on this would be appreciated.

your application is running on localhost then you need to set it up so that its running on your domain.
